# Can this component be identified? Top mark is 2B with a sideways F

Tags: identification, surface-mount, gpu

What do you think, does this look right?

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/PMPB215ENEA-1600076.pdf

Short is gone........

[image: Short is gone...]This is the 1V rail for a GTX 2060 GPU which is currently shorted. I'm going to pull it and if I can buzz out the traces. Any help would be appreciated. It's marked 2B with a sideways F.

[image: photo 1 of PCB]

[image: photo 2 of PCB]

Comment: Since its PCB designation is Q637. it is probably some type of transistor.

Comment: Most likely an xx mOhm FET

Comment: Maybe there is a SMPS chip nearby and you can find the datasheet for it. It’s a very high frequency supply with only a 2.2uH inductor,

Comment: This is a consumer device repair question in disguise, isn't it?

Comment: "Maybe there is a SMPS chip nearby and you can find the datasheet for it. It’s a very high frequency supply with only a 2.2uH inductor, "– Spehro Pefhany                     That's brilliant, thanks, I'll see what I can find.

Comment: "This is a consumer device repair question in disguise, isn't it?" – mmmm  --------          Is this a question? Or some sort of implication?

Comment: I would look at 10mOhm Pch FETs with low Ciss. >1MHz Buck regulator

Comment: "I would look at 10mOhm Pch FETs with low Ciss. >1MHz Buck regulator"– @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 ----  will do thanks.

Comment: Was the FET shorted? If it was, the 12V supply might have ended up to the 1V supply or to the gate driver chip output pin. Both scenarios look plausible, so most likely changing the FET still leaves you with a broken video card. You need to check if everything else is not broken.